# What does a|b in Integerrings mean?

Tags: integer-rings

What does a|b in Integerrings mean ? How to read it ?

Found it in german wikipedia under 'Struktursatz über zyklische Arithmetik':
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage-Strassen-Algorithmus